# Расчёт углов треугольника

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Пмогите, пожалуйста. Кажется, формулы правильно написал, но почему-то не те значения пишет. Проверял на нескольких сайтах. Там результаты одни, а тут другие.

```
document.getElementById("result_btn").onclick = function count(){
    var a, b, c, resultAlpha, resultBeta, resultGamma;
    a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    a = parseInt(a);

    b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    b = parseInt(b);

    c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    c = parseInt(c);

    if(isNaN(a) && isNaN(b) && isNaN(c)){
        alert("Ой! Помилка...");
    }
    else{
        if(a + b < c || b + c < a || a + c < b){
            alert("Одна сторона не може бути більшою за суму двох інших сторін.");
        }
        else{
            resultAlpha = Math.cos((Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(b, 2)) / 2 * a * c) * 180 / Math.PI;
            document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = resultAlpha;
            resultBeta = Math.cos((Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2) - Math.pow(c, 2)) / 2 * a * b) * 180 / Math.PI;
            document.getElementById("out2").innerHTML = resultBeta;
            resultGamma = Math.cos((Math.pow(b, 2) + Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(a, 2)) / 2 * c * b) * 180 / Math.PI;
            document.getElementById("out3").innerHTML = resultGamma;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас формула неправильная какая-то.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
document.getElementById("result_btn").onclick = function count(){
    var a, b, c, resultAlpha, resultBeta, resultGamma;
    a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    a = parseInt(a);

    b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    b = parseInt(b);

    c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    c = parseInt(c);

    if(isNaN(a) && isNaN(b) && isNaN(c)){
        alert("Ой! Помилка...");
    }
    else{
        if(a + b < c || b + c < a || a + c < b){
            alert("Одна сторона не може бути більшою за суму двох інших сторін.");
        }
        else{
            resultAlpha = Math.acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2) / (2 * b * c)) * 180 / Math.PI;
            document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = resultAlpha;
            resultBeta = Math.acos((c**2 + a**2 - b**2) / (2 * a * c)) * 180 / Math.PI;
            document.getElementById("out2").innerHTML = resultBeta;
            resultGamma = 180 - resultAlpha - resultBeta;
            document.getElementById("out3").innerHTML = resultGamma;
        }
    }

}
```

```html
<button id="result_btn">рассчитать</button>
<br>
Стороны
<br>
<input id="a" placeholder="a"/>
<input id="b" placeholder="b"/>
<input id="c" placeholder="c"/>
<br>
Ответы
<br>
<div id="out1" placeholder="a"></div>
<div id="out2" placeholder="b"></div>
<div id="out3" placeholder="c"></div>
```